# How can I use Python to open "~/.bash_profile"

Tags: python, bash

I want to use Python to edit `~/.bash_profile`, but when I run these codes:

```
f = open('~/.bash_profile', 'rb')
```

it told me:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.bash_profile'
```

I thought it was because `~/.bash_profile` is a system protect file.
Is there any method to open this file by using Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally `~` is expanded by the shell, not by the system call. In Python, use [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand paths starting with `~`.